# How to create a virtual device with Play Store AND hardware acceleration?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to play with google maps APIs in Android Studio. 
The AVD seems to only have two profiles "out of the box", that have Play Store - Nexus 5, and Nexus 5X, but both of them have "Graphics" set to "Automatic" and grayed out (I cannot change it).

When I try to use Google Maps with either of those, it fails, complaining that it needs GL ES 2.0 acceleration.

I tried creating a new device profile, (with API level 27), and that lets me enable graphics acceleration ... but does not have Play Store. Now, when I run it, it says, that Google Maps needs to update Google Play, and crashes after I click Ok.

Any idea? How can I create a virtual device, that has both Play Store and hardware acceleration enabled?

Answer (score -1):

Use Genymotion. It's faster than AVD. After installing it click on top right widget. It will install gapps.
[image]

Comment: I am not ready to pay money for the tooling yet. Just playing around to explore the apis

Comment: You don't have to buy. Get free version. There are some restrictions. But it's enough to test.

Comment: There is no free version, only a trial one.